# How to monitor tethering bandwidth

Tags: tethering, 3g, resource-monitoring

Is there any way to monitor 3G *tethering* usage. ie excluding regular 3G bandwidth. (This is for a UK GiffGaff plan, where normal use is unlimited, but tethering charged per GB.)

Comment: We prefer questions that ask how to solve problems, not questions where a solution is already selected (an app) and the question solicits recommendations (opinions). In other words, "how do I do X" is better than "is there an app that does X".

Comment: Updated as such.

Comment: @mahemoff: Do you have to use a special tethering app? Because usually a mobile network operator can not distinguish between traffic caused by the smartphone and a thethered computer. I only know special data plans for computers using a second SIM card (and own UMTS modem) on the same contract - but that has nothing to do with tethering

Comment: Robert, nope, no special app required. I realise there's no magic way to do it, I'm presuming they just try sniffing for non-mobile packets, e.g. a desktop browser header.
I mentioned the plan (see http://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2011/10/giffgaff-unlocks-tethering-potential-with-gigabags-mobile-data-plans/) - because no matter how accurate/feasible, they're definitely charging it, so users need to know how to measure it.

Comment: Mobile networks can definitely tell the difference. I don't know how, but I know they can.

Comment: @Dest sounds interesting do you have a link with more information?

Comment: I don't, just google and you'll find varying info. It probably varies from carrier to carrier.

Comment: Actually in this case, I found out after asking this that GiffGaff doesn't actually make the distinction. If you take their tethering option, the whole thing (including mobile use) is suddenly capped.

Answer (score 1):

If you're rooted you could try [Wireless Tether for Root Users](https://market.android.com/details?id=android.tether).

More info and more recent versions here: https://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/

Besides having way more options than the stock wifi tether application it also allows you to have a look at the bandwith used when tethering is active.